# Showing something other than ID in scaffold Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I setup associations in my models:

```
class User extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'User';
    var $hasMany = array('Post' => array('className' => 'Post'));
}
```

and

```
class Post extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Post';
    var $belongsTo = array('User' => array('className' => 'User'));
}
```

Which work great, except in the scaffold, the User dropdown list shows the ID number and not the username. (Username is a column) How do I get it to show the username instead of id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add following to your User model:

```
var $displayField = 'username';
```

Comment: Scary how well this worked. I will accept this answer in 6 minutes. Lame I have to wait, but thank you for such a quick and sexy response.