# Cakephp displayField .. more than one in model

Tags: cakephp

This other question

[Showing something other than ID in scaffold Cakephp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817887/showing-something-other-than-id-in-scaffold-cakephp)

has been answered in many places here and elsewhere and deals with situation where I want a select list but the text field to show instead of id is not named 'Name'. Apparently, Cake can handle this if you tell it what the field is named instaed of 'Name' by putting the following in its Model:

```
var $displayField = 'NonNameName';
```

However, all examples are for one select. But i have three select lists so how do i add them?  Of course I can't do the as the following code shows (eg three lines of "var $displayField = "...";" ..  it doesn't make sense to have three $displayField ..

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
/**
 * Visit Model
 *
 * @property User $User
 * @property Referrer $Referrer
 * @property Company $Company
 */
class Visit extends AppModel {

    //The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are not needed can be removed

/**
 * belongsTo associations
 *
 * @var array
 */

var $displayField = 'location';
var $displayField = 'referrer';
var $displayField = 'company';


    public $belongsTo = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ),
        'Referrer' => array(
            'className' => 'Referrer',
            'foreignKey' => 'referrer_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ),
        'Location' => array(
            'className' => 'Location',
            'foreignKey' => 'location_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ),      
        'Company' => array(
            'className' => 'Company',
            'foreignKey' => 'company_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );
}
```

In my controller I have

```
$companies= $this->Visit->Company->find('list');
$locations = $this->Visit->Location->find('list', array('conditions' => array('company_id' => $this->Auth->user('company_id'))));
$referrers = $this->Visit->Referrer->find('list', array('conditions' => array('company_id' => $this->Auth->user('company_id'))));   
    $this->set(compact('locations','referrers','companies'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you mean to do is this:

```
// controller/action
$locations = $this->Visit->Location->find('list');
$referrers = $this->Visit->Referrer->find('list');
$companies = $this->Visit->Company->find('list');
$this->set(compact('locations', 'referrers', 'companies'));
```

in your view:

```
echo $this->Form->input('location_id');
echo $this->Form->input('referrer_id');
echo $this->Form->input('company_id');
```

That (should) produce three selects - mimicking the `display-field` behaviour you are after.

To quote cake:

> find('list', $params) returns an indexed array, useful for any use
>   where you would want a list such as for populating input select boxes.

http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1022/find-list

Comment: Sorry, I was relying on prev post to convey info.  I already did what you suggest Ross.  Cake depends on text fields to show instead of id being named 'Name' to automagically show text instead of id.  However, I do not want to name them 'Name'.  No problem, bc apparently Cake covers this by allowing me to put "var $displayField = 'username';" in model to tell Cake the 'Name' fields are 'Location', 'Referrer' and 'Company'.  However, all examples i can find are for only one not three non 'Name' fields.  What is syntax and where do i put these?

Comment: Put `$displayField=`Field` in each model. So your `Location` model's display field is `location` - assuming you have a field called `location` in your table. Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: Ah, ok!  That does it.  Thanks!  My confusion was around where it went.  All discussions of it are focused on the model in which the select is used.  But none (at least that I inferred) specifically said to put var $displayField = 'ModelNameName'; into the model it belongs to, not the model you want it to show in.  Of course, now it seems perfectly obvious.

Answer (score 1):

In CakePHP 3.x, the best and documented and elegant way is :

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#customize-key-value-output

It is possible to use closures to access entity accessor methods in your list finds like this :

```
// In your Authors Entity create a virtual field to be used as the displayField:
protected function _getLabel()
{
    return $this->_properties['first_name'] . ' ' . $this->_properties['last_name']
      . ' / ' . __('User ID %s', $this->_properties['user_id']);
}
```

Then you can fetch the label in the list finder directly using :

```
// In AuthorsTable::initialize():
$this->setDisplayField('label'); // Will utilize Author::_getLabel()
// In your finders/controller:
$query = $authors->find('list'); // Will utilize AuthorsTable::getDisplayField()
// In your views:
$author->label // will display : John Doe / User ID 123
```

Answer (score 0):

In CakePHP 3.x:

Open your App/Model/Table/Your_Table.php

```
public function initialize(array $config) {
    $this->displayField(['full_name', 'email']);
}
```

When you retrieving list:

```
TableRegistry::get('Your')->find('list');
```

Result will be:

```
[
    [key => 'full_name;email'],
    [key => 'full_name;email'],
];
```